# set cookie in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, cookies

**I am new to zend framework.** I have write this code to set cookie in my website.

```
public function setCookie($data){
    $email_cookie = new Zend_Http_Cookie('user_email_id', $data['user_email_id'], $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '', FALSE);
    $pass_cookie = new Zend_Http_Cookie('user_password', $data['user_password'], $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '', FALSE);
    $cookie_jar = new Zend_Http_CookieJar();
    $cookie_jar->addCookie($email_cookie);
    $cookie_jar->addCookie($pass_cookie);
}
```

I dont even know by writing this code, my cookie is set or not? 
now If I want to retrieve the cookie then how can I do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Zend_Http_Cookie` is not for setting cookies. It is a class used by `Zend_Http_Client` for sending and receiving data from sites that require cookies. To set cookies just use the standard PHP [setcookie()](http://www.php.net/setcookie) function:

```
setcookie('user_email_id', $data['user_email_id'], time() + 3600, '/');
setcookie('user_password', $data['user_password'], time() + 3600, '/');
```

this will set cookies that expire in 1 hour. You can then access these on subsequent requests using `$_COOKIE['user_email_id']` and `$_COOKIE['user_password']`; or if you are using ZF's MVC classes: `$this->getRequest()->getCookie('user_email_id')` (from a controller method).

Comment: The `$this->getRequest()->getCookie('user_email_id')` returns a cookie object. Now, how to get the value from that cookie object ?

Answer (score 2):

Your cookies are set by sending response. You can modify response in your code.

```
$cookie = new Zend_Http_Header_SetCookie();
$cookie->setName('foo')
       ->setValue('bar')
       ->setDomain('example.com')
       ->setPath('/')
       ->setHttponly(true);
$this->getResponse()->setRawHeader($cookie);
```

By default, the front controller sends response when it has finished dispatching the request; typically you will never need to call it. 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.response.html

Comment: +1. However be careful with `setRawHeader($cookie)` because some http clients (for example, **ASIHTTP** in Objective-C) will rewrite all cookies set up before headers will send.
 Use `$this->getResponse()->setHeader($cookie->getFieldName(), $cookie->getFieldValue());` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Zend_Http_Cookie](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.cookies.html)

You will get your cookie like following:

```
echo $email_cookie->getName(); // user_email_id
echo $email_cookie->getValue(); // Your cookie value

echo ($email_cookie->isExpired() ? 'Yes' : 'No'); // Check coookie is expired or not
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use this way you can do it**

in your controller do it code as

```
$cookie = new Zend_Http_Cookie('cookiename',
                        'cookievalue',
                         time() + 7200 //expires after 2 hrs
                       );
echo $cookie->__toString();
echo $cookie->getName(); //cookie name
echo $cookie->getValue(); //cookie value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ret_as = COOKIE_STRING_ARRAY;
Zend_Http_CookieJar->getAllCookies($ret_as); 
//Get all cookies from the jar. $ret_as specifies the return type 
//as described above. If not specified, $ret_type defaults to COOKIE_OBJECT.
```

Ref: [Zend Cookies](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.cookies.html)

Comment: thats the return type, you can use: COOKIE_STRING_ARRAY, COOKIE_STRING_CONCAT. If nothing is specified default is COOKIE_OBJECT as return type