# ZF2 setCookie not working

Tags: php, cookies, zend-framework2

Since a while I am trying to figure out why setting a cookie through ZF2 seems to be so hard? Probably it isn't but I can't figure out why the cookie isn't set.

Code

```
use Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie;

    $response        = $this->getResponse()->getHeaders();
    $cookiesAccepted = new SetCookie('accepted_cookies', 1, strtotime('+1 Year', time()), '/');
    $cookieTest      = new SetCookie('test_key', 'test_value', strtotime('+1 Year', time()), '/');
    $response        ->addHeader($cookiesAccepted);
    $response        ->addHeader($cookieTest);
```

Refreshing page.

Testing output by dump

```
Debug::dump($_COOKIE);
```

Doesn't contain the 'accepted_cookies' or 'test_key' cookie.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set cookie in zend framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514879/set-cookie-in-zend-framework)

Comment: @EatPeanutButter That link is a question related to zend framework 1 not zend framework 2

Comment: It's ZF2 indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set cookies in the response object and dumping `$_COOKIE` will not immediately give you the cookies that you added to your response object.

When using cookies in Zend Framework 2 there is no need to interact with the super global directly. Check also [the documentation for reference](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.http.cookie.handling.html).

You could try like this in your next request object:

```
$accepted_cookies = $this->getRequest()->getHeaders()->get('Cookie')->accepted_cookies;
$test_key = $this->getRequest()->getHeaders()->get('Cookie')->test_key;
```

Check also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14264267/1697459) for more examples on cookie management.

Comment: I've tried to refresh many times and ouput cookies on different pages to check the results. None showed up

Comment: @directory Updated my answer